# Access VS Code api from WebView

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For an extension development, I am creating a webview where there are buttons in which on click of it should execute some commands in vscode (Like opening Dialog boxes)

Currently I am using React to create the WebView

Eg Code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as vscode from 'vscode'
class .... {

public render() {
<div className="some" onClick={this.function1} role="button">
                            Test
                        </div>
}

private function1() {  vscode.commands.executeCommand("commandString"); }

}
```

I am getting error

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vscode' in "

when running webpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly interact with vscode in your webview. Instead there are message APIs to send and receive (string) data. You could use that to specify a command to execute. Sending a message from the extension to the webview is described in [this section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-an-extension-to-a-webview).

Here's the essential part of it:

```
    // Handle the message inside the webview
    window.addEventListener('message', event => {

        const message = event.data; // The JSON data our extension sent

        switch (message.command) {
            case 'refactor':
                count = Math.ceil(count * 0.5);
                counter.textContent = count;
                break;
        }
    });
```

And for the other direction read [this section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-a-webview-to-an-extension).

Here's the essential part of it:

```
  panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(
    message => {
      switch (message.command) {
        case 'alert':
          vscode.window.showErrorMessage(message.text);
          return;
      }
    },
    undefined,
    context.subscriptions
  );
```

Comment: Should this be a duplicate of your other answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830928/calling-vscode-extension-for-data-from-webview?

Comment: From an answer standpoint yes, but the questions target different aspects (accessing vscode API versus sending data). Keeping the questions separate helps people search for one solution or the other.